# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid encountered while trying to run app in ios simulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I get thrown the below error whenever i try running my app on an ios simulator

[image]

It keeps telling me to check the render method of "_class2" which i absolutely don't know it's location.

Below are my export and import files

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import configureStore from "./src/Store/configureStore"
import React from "react"

const store= configureStore()

const Root = () => (
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App/>
    </Provider>
);



AppRegistry.registerComponent('Fluffy', () => Root);
```

App.js

```
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {Navigation} from "react-native-navigation"

import OnboardingScreen from "./src/screens/OnboardingScreen"
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen"
import NewsScreen from "./src/screens/NewsScreen"
import ProfileScreen from "./src/screens/ProfileScreen"
import CartScreen from "./src/screens/CartScreen"
import ProfileInfoScreen from "./src/screens/ProfileInfoScreen"
import OrderScreen from "./src/screens/OrderScreen"
import configureStore from "./src/Store/configureStore"

const store = configureStore()

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.OnboardingScreen", ()=> OnboardingScreen,Provider,store)
Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.HomeScreen",
 ()=>HomeScreen,
 store,
 Provider
 )
Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.NewsScreen", ()=> NewsScreen,
store,
Provider)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.ProfileScreen",
 ()=> ProfileScreen,
 Provider,
 store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.CartScreen",
 ()=> CartScreen,
 Provider,
 store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.ProfileInfoScreen", 
()=>ProfileInfoScreen,
Provider,
store)

Navigation.registerComponent("fluffy.OrderScreen", 
()=> OrderScreen,
Provider,
store)

export default () => Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
screen : {
  screen: "fluffy.OnboardingScreen",
}
})
```

Thanks in advance for all your assistance!

Comment: this might help https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332#issuecomment-341911775

Comment: The errors clearly tell you that it is in renderApplication.js line 33. Btw you have another mistakes here , sinces you're exporting a default class / component and it is not function you should changed to export default () => Navigation.startSingleScreenApp....

Comment: Thanks amir but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes digit, i actually used your suggestion in my earlier stages and didn't seem to work also.

Comment: I still don't understand why it keeps saying it received an object! I clearly exported a function as default.

Comment: This may not be related, but why `store` and `Provider` order is different in the line for `'fluffy.NewsScreen'`?

Comment: No specific reason really vahissan. I really didn't even notice it until now, but it won't alter the execution of the app.
Ohh snap!! You are a genius sir! hahaha that was the problem all along. OMG!! I cannot believe this. Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: Add it as an answer so that i can approve!